# Java.Lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list' in c# xamarin

Tags: c#, asp.net, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am trying to make an android app using `C#` in which I want to bind some data in `listview` using `asmx` webservices.

Here is my code-

**MainActivity.cs**

```
public class MainActivity : ListActivity
    {
        int count = 1;
        EditText txtGRN;
        EditText txtTcode;
        TextView lblMessage;                                                                                                                                  
        Button Callservicebutton1;
        protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate (bundle);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);

            // Get our button from the layout resource,
            // and attach an event to it
            Button button = FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.myButton);

            button.Click += delegate {
                button.Text = string.Format ("{0} clicks!", count++);
            };
            Button renderpage = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.RenderPage);
            renderpage.Click += delegate {
                StartActivity(typeof(RenderPage1));
            };
            txtGRN = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.txtGRN);
            txtTcode = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.txtCode);
            lblMessage = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.lblmessage);

            Callservicebutton1 = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.BtnServiceCall);

            Callservicebutton1.Click += Callservicebutton1_Click;
        }
  private void Callservicebutton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            ServiceUrl1.Service1 service1 = new ServiceUrl1.Service1();

            ServiceUrlNew.AndriodService Objandrodservice = new ServiceUrlNew.AndriodService();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            var data = Objandrodservice.GetBankDetails();

            string[] items;
            items = new string[] { Objandrodservice.GetBankDetails() };

            ListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, items);



            ListView lstDisplayBankData = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.LstBankData);
             }

        private void Service_GetGrnVoucherStringCompleted(object sender, ServiceUrl.GetGrnVoucherStringCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            Callservicebutton1.Enabled = true;
            lblMessage.Text = "calling service";
        }
    }
}
```

**Main.axml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/myButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello" />
    <Button
        android:text="Render Page"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/RenderPage" />
    <EditText
        android:text="GRN"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/txtGRN" />
    <EditText
        android:text="TCode"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/txtCode" />
    <Button
        android:text="Call Service"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/BtnServiceCall" />
    <TextView
        android:text="View Message"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/lblmessage" />
    <ListView
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/LstBankData" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I am simply trying to bind data in listview. but I get an error `OnCreate` at `SetContentView`-

> Java.Lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

List Activity should contain list with @android:id/list  change your listviews id

```
<ListView
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@android:id/list" />
```

Comment: Thanks, this means android id with `"@android:id/list"` is necessary to identify `simplellistitem` in `ListAdapter`.

Comment: Only if you are using a ListActivity